Can't change url because site address is greyed out
I'm completely new to this. I set up a new website using Elementor (Hosting) and am using Wordpress.
I logged into Elementor and they told me to get a domain name. Makes sense, so I bought my domain from Easyhost.
Then I followed all the DNS steps they required of me. Put in the A-record, the CNAME record, everything so it could connect. And it did so successfully or so Elementor says.
Now here is the problem.. I bought the domains disruptivedatasociety.com and www.disruptivedatasociety.com but when I open the website, it uses a weird url with elementor in it: https://xldiddts.elementor.cloud/ instead of using the domain I bought.
When I went to the settings area of Wordpress to change this, the whole area is greyed out. I can't change the site address, which I think is where the right url should be no?
When someone types in the domain url I bought, they end up on the right website but it always shows this ugly elementor url instead. How can i fix this?
If it's not clear, I'm a total newbie so please bear with me - I am trying my best to explain.

This is a question for Elementor Hosting as it's not a WordPress question itself.  Hosting providers like Elementor Hosting and FlyWheel don't use traditional and default WP routes and settings for these things. With FlyWheel the wp-config.php is actually sandboxed and can't be edited, it's just there for reference.  You should reach out to their support.

Check in wp-config.php in the root directory of your site, if the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME constants are hard-coded there the corresponding boxes in the settings will be greyed out as you describe.

How do I access this wp-config? I used WinSCP to download it onto my computer but now I need to use cPanel? But Elementor says it doesn't use cPanel so how else do I open the wp-config.php?

You should be able to open it in any text editor. Notepad++ is a free and widely available option.

I find this:
define('WP_HOME', 'https://xldiddts.elementor.cloud');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://xldiddts.elementor.cloud');
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
So i assume it's hard coded?

All you need to do is replace the 'xldiddts.elementor.cloud' with 'www.disruptivedatasociety.com' in both places, save the file and upload it again, overwriting the original.

Do I upload it with the WinSCP thing again then? There won't be a double file or something to make it crash?

Yup. It should ask if you want to overwrite.

Now it doesn't work anymore... I get this error= This page isn’t workingwww.disruptivedatasociety.com redirected you too many times.

I can't even log in anymore in my back-end of Wordpress

Ok. Revert the changes and reupload the file, it looks like they're doing something non-standard behind the scenes to integrate it with their hosting panel. Then follow the instructions here: https://elementor.com/help/add-a-custom-domain-name-for-your-elementor-hosted-website/

Okay so I did that but now when I see my website the entire lay-out is completely broken... When I try to log into my WP admin it's also completely stripped of lay-out and when I put in my credentials it won't connect. I'm afraid I broke my entire website..

This is the error I received when i log into the back-end: This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in https.
If spelling is correct, try running windows network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
